# Is it a good idea to set file permissions to 640 on windows partition?

Tags: permissions, windows, chmod

I run both Arch Linux and Windows 10 on my computer. When I `cd` onto the Windows partition (which uses NTFS), I notice that all files and folders have `777` file permissions. I want to run
`$ chmod 640 -R *` from the partition's root directory to set all file and folder permissions to what they are normally on my linux partition, but I'm a little afraid it might mess up Windows. Is it safe to run this command? Same applies to my external USB hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Permissions" on NTFS file-systems are a mount option.  NTFS doesn't support unix style permissions, `ntfs-3g` has to fake it with NTFS ACLs.

Use `umask=027` on the `mount` command line (or in `/etc/fstab`) to get permissions of `640`.

See `man mount.ntfs` for more details and options.

Comment: No, that is not true. NTFS does support file permissions. I just tested it.

Comment: ntfs-3g fakes unix perms on NTFS.  read the man page.  see also http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/

Comment: Oh, that explains why it worked. So, if permissions are not acually set, is it correct to assume that windows doesn't even know about them and thus it is safe to chance permissions?

Comment: personally, i'd use the `umask` etc mount-time options and only run chmod on files and dirs that need to be different from the default.  as the doc i linked to mentions, faking chmod/chown involves lots of ACLs per file.  that's got to slow down filesystem access if every file and dir has its own individual set of ACLs that need to be interpreted.

Comment: Good point, but how do I set different defaults for files and folders? It would be nice to have execution rights on folders by default so I can enter them.

Comment: that's what the `umask` mount option is for.  `umask=027` will result in `640` for files and `750` for directories.